# Count distinct grouped documents across all values of a facet

Tags: solr

**Solr 8.8**

I have a typical `group` configuration for aggregating documents.

```
group=true&group.field=group_key&group.limit=-1
```

For facet counts per facet value at the `group` level, I'm using the [JSON facet API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/json-facet-api.html):

```json
{
   "height":{
      "field":"height",
      "mincount":1,
      "limit":-1,
      "facet":{
         "facet_count":"unique(group_field)"
      },
      "domain":{
         "excludeTags":"height"
      },
      "type":"terms"
   }
}
```

**Clarification** This code allows me to see the count of grouped items for a particular facet. Each group can only increment a facet count by 1. For example, if a product has three variants - 2 green and 1 red, the facet count for Green will be 1 and the count for Red will be 1.

How can I query the total number of **grouped** documents across all values of a facet?

**Clarification** I am querying Solr to get the most popular facets for a particular set of documents. For example, for a text search of "dishwasher", 100 (grouped) products are returned. How many of those products have a truthy value for Color? If 60 products have a Color value, the Color facet is important enough to show to the user.

For **non**-grouped documents I can query using `countvals` or `missing` (see [docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/json-facet-api.html#types-of-facets)):

```json
{
   "height":{
      "field":"height",
      "mincount":1,
      "limit":-1,
      "facet":{
         "countvals":"countvals(height)",
         "missing":"missing(height)",
      },
      "domain":{
         "excludeTags":"height"
      },
      "type":"query"
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to accomplish? I have a hard time parsing your question and how it differs from what you've shown in your two examples.

Comment: @MatsLindh I added **Clarification** sections to the post.